# Irregular temporal data and visualization

Tags: arcgis-desktop, time, spatio-temporal-data

I want to add timed data to ArcGIS. The problem is that the data is very bulky and in Excel file there are two columns of date and time of start and end of the interval and these intervals are irregular, for example some under one hour, some are hours and some are days.

Is there a way to automatically introduce these two columns to the software and software identify start and end by itself?
Is it possible to show these data on time slider while the intervals are not equal?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Have you tried Excel To Table and then Join Field?

Comment: I'm using Arcmap and  my major problem is that the data intervals are irregular some under one hour, some are hours and some are days.so that i cant introduce special interval in software.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us a sample of your data, you don't even mention any spatial aspect of your data.